# T-SQL - Update column with calculated values from previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my sample data

```
    declare @MyTable TABLE(ClientId int, RecNo int, PaidAmt decimal(12, 2), PaidBefore decimal(12,2),
    ReimbToDate decimal(12,2), CanReimb decimal(12,2), BalBeforeReimb decimal(12, 2), 
    ReimbAmt decimal(12, 2), BalAfterReimb decimal(12, 2) )

insert into @MyTable (ClientId, RecNo, PaidAmt, PaidBefore, ReimbToDate, CanReimb, BalBeforeReimb ) select 1, 1, 100, 0, 0, 0 ,250
insert into @MyTable (ClientId, RecNo, PaidAmt, PaidBefore, ReimbToDate) select 1, 2, 400, 0, 0
insert into @MyTable (ClientId, RecNo, PaidAmt, PaidBefore, ReimbToDate) select 1, 3,-200 ,0 ,0

insert into @MyTable (ClientId ,RecNo ,PaidAmt ,PaidBefore ,ReimbToDate ,CanReimb,BalBeforeReimb) select 2 ,1 ,900 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,3000
insert into @MyTable (ClientId ,RecNo ,PaidAmt ,PaidBefore ,ReimbToDate) select 2 ,2 ,300 ,0 ,0
insert into @MyTable (ClientId ,RecNo ,PaidAmt ,PaidBefore ,ReimbToDate) select 2 ,3 ,1600 ,0 ,0
insert into @MyTable (ClientId ,RecNo ,PaidAmt ,PaidBefore ,ReimbToDate) select 2 ,4 ,-900 ,900 ,900
insert into @MyTable (ClientId ,RecNo ,PaidAmt ,PaidBefore ,ReimbToDate) select 2 ,5 ,-300 ,300 ,300
insert into @MyTable (ClientId ,RecNo,PaidAmt,PaidBefore,ReimbToDate) select 2,6,750,0,0
insert into @MyTable (ClientId ,RecNo,PaidAmt,PaidBefore,ReimbToDate) select 2,7,625,0,0
insert into @MyTable (ClientId ,RecNo,PaidAmt,PaidBefore,ReimbToDate) select 2,8,125,625,625
```

Other Columns are calculated as follow:

CanReimb = PaidAmt + PaidBefore - ReimbToDate

BalBeforeReimb is BalAfterReimb of previous row of same client when RecNo is not 1

ReimbAmt is minimum of CanReimb and BalBeforeReimb

BalAfterReimb = BalBeforeReimb - ReimbAmt

I need output as follow:

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: hmm, but where do you get balbeforereimb for first row? is that the only one that is "set" and rest must be calculated?

Comment: I do not understand the test data or results but:

 1. Due to calculations being dependant on previous calcuations, Window functions will not work.
 2. I would be inclined to do this with a DataReader in the middle tier.
 3. If you really need to do this with t-sql then use a cursor, recursion or the Quirky Update.

 The Quirky update is likly to be the fastest t-sql solution but be aware it is non-relational and undocumented by Microsoft so is not officially supported. Caveat Emptor!

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten

Comment: As a clustered index is required use the following:
  
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MyTable;
 CREATE TABLE #MyTable
 (
   ClientId int NOT NULL
   ,RecNo int NOT NULL
   ,PaidAmt decimal(12, 2) NOT NULL
   ,PaidBefore decimal(12,2) NOT NULL
   ,ReimbToDate decimal(12,2) NOT NULL
   ,CanReimb decimal(12,2) NULL
   ,BalBeforeReimb decimal(12, 2) NULL
   ,ReimbAmt decimal(12, 2) NULL
   ,BalAfterReimb decimal(12, 2) NULL
   -- Need a clustered index for Quirky Upate to work
   ,PRIMARY KEY (ClientId, RecNo)
);

Comment: INSERT INTO #MyTable (ClientId, RecNo, PaidAmt, PaidBefore, ReimbToDate, BalBeforeReimb)
VALUES (1, 1, 100, 0, 0, 250)
   ,(1, 2, 400, 0, 0, NULL)
   /* Assuming
      PaidBefore should be 400 not 0
      ReimbToDate should be 150 not 0   */
   ,(1, 3,-200 ,400 ,150, NULL)
   ,(2 ,1 ,900 ,0 ,0, 3000)
   ,(2 ,2 ,300 ,0 ,0, NULL)
   ,(2 ,3 ,1600 ,0 ,0, NULL)
   ,(2 ,4 ,-900 ,900 ,900, NULL)
   ,(2 ,5 ,-300 ,300 ,300, NULL)
   ,(2,6,750,0,0, NULL)
   ,(2,7,625,0,0, NULL)
   ,(2,8,125,625,625, NULL);
 
select * from #MyTable;

Comment: DECLARE @CanReimb decimal(12, 2)
   ,@BalBeforeReimb decimal(12, 2)
   ,@BalAfterReimb decimal(12, 2)
   ,@ReimbAmt decimal(12, 2)
   ,@check int
   ,@ClientId int
   ,@RecNo int;

Comment: @siggemannen - yes balforreimb is coming from other table for recno = 1 for each client.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code based on your request, because I don't know the data, I didn't test the data

```
select 
ClientId
,RecNo
,PaidAmt
,PaidBefore
,CanReimb
,BalBeforeReimb
,ReimbAmt=case when CanReimb<BalBeforeReimb then CanReimb else BalBeforeReimb end,
BalAfterReimb=BalBeforeReimb-ReimbAmt

from (
        select ClientId,RecNo,PaidAmt,PaidBefore,CanReimb,ReimbAmt,case when  RecNo<>1 then 
        LAG (BalBeforeReimb) over (partition by ClientId order by ClientId) else 0 end as BalBeforeReimb

        from @MyTable
)a
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yNglZP_k)

Comment: No, it does not give the results as desired. It turns all BalAfterReimb null, which miscalculate other columns too

Comment: please example data because, CanReimb and  BalAfterReimb  is wrong (CanReimb use example with calculation)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add CanReimb Formula, CanReimb = PaidAmt + PaidBefore - ReimbToDate - I am editing in original post too.

Comment: your example data with result is different(example: Row 3 of PaidBefore in pic =400 and PaidBefore of example =0)
please check whole base data(ClientId,RecNo,PaidAmt,PaidBefore,ReimbAmt)

Comment: CanReimb = PaidAmt + PaidBefore - ReimbToDate = -200 + 400 - 150 = 50
BalBeforeReimb = Previous Row BalAfterReimb = 0
ReimbAmt = minimum of CanReimb and BalBeforeReimb = 0
BalAfterReimb = BalBeforeReimb - ReimbAmt = 0 - 0 = 0

Comment: I understand the formula. Your sample data is different from the final result. Do this query and you will understand . select PaidAmt , PaidBefore , ReimbToDate 
from @MyTable
where ClientId=1 and RecNo=3